# How do you implement a Google search area into an Android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to add a search bar into an Android app that will open a browser to search Google. How would this be done in the simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an Edittext and a Button and if someone click on the button get the text from the edittext (`getText()`), and cear the EditText. After that you can create the url string from "www.google.com/#q=" plus the text and finally you can do:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

That's all, I hope it's helped.